Swagger asking for login credentials even though url is permitted through Spring Security configuration classes
I have added Swagger to my Spring Boot app and can access
http://localhost:8081/v3/api-docs without any issue, but for http://localhost:8081/swagger-ui/index.html#/ I keep being asked for login credentials, even though the Swagger api is permitted through my request matchers.

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.security.config.Customizer;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;

import static com.francislainy.sobe.enums.UserRole.ADMIN;
import static com.francislainy.sobe.enums.UserRole.USER;

@Configuration
public class WebAuthorizationConfig {

    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .cors(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults());

        http.authorizeHttpRequests(
                c -> c
                        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/v1/test-admin").hasRole(String.valueOf(ADMIN)) //todo: remove this endpoint once new valid endpoints are added - 06/11/2024
                        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/v1/test-user").hasRole(String.valueOf(USER)) //todo: remove this endpoint once new valid endpoints are added - 06/11/2024
                        .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/v1/auth/*").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers("/swagger-ui/**", "/v3/api-docs/**", "/swagger-resources/**", "/webjars/**", "/v2/api-docs/**").permitAll() // Allow access to Swagger UI
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        );

        http.csrf(
                c -> c.disable()
        );

        return http.build();
    }
}


These are my Swagger dependencies:
        <!-- Swagger dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
            <version>${springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.swagger.parser.v3</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-parser</artifactId>
            <version>${swagger-parser.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.yaml</groupId>
            <artifactId>snakeyaml</artifactId>
            <version>${snakeyaml.version}</version> <!-- A compatible version for swagger-parser -->
        </dependency>
        <!-- end of Swagger dependencies -->

 <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui.version>2.6.0</springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui.version>
        <swagger-parser.version>2.0.31</swagger-parser.version>
        <snakeyaml.version>1.32</snakeyaml.version>
 </properties>


Spring boot <version>3.3.5</version>
The whole project is here:
https://github.com/francislainy/so-be
Thank you.
PS: We are using swagger-parser and snakeyaml dependencies as we are configuring swagger through an openapi.yml file and without them only /v3/api-docs is accessible (with or without security enabled), but the issue still happens without these dependencies when using only the simpler default swagger implementation.


I am not really sure because configuring swagger was something I did last year, but I remember that I had added some extra swagger properties in application.properties as well as a configuration OpenAPI bean. I can share them to you if you want. I think it is something I found reading the docs.

Sure, please, if you can share what you have and I can try and see whether it will fix the issue. Thank you so much.

Not sure why you are defining dependencies for specific versions of swagger-parser and snakeyaml. For the current spring-boot-starter-parent version (3.3.5) the only dependency needed is:
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
    <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.0</version>
</dependency>

And in the security filter chain:
// ...
    .requestMatchers("/swagger-ui/**", "/v3/api-docs/**").permitAll()
// ...

With the above settings Swagger UI shows without login. Tested today.
The above is the default and lets Swagger generate the specification programmatically from all exposed endpoints. If you want to use your own specification you need to add your file to the src/main/resources/static/ folder and set the properties as follows:
# OpenAPI
springdoc.api-docs.enabled=false # important! otherwise Swagger generate the docs from endpoints
springdoc.swagger-ui.url=/openapi.yml

You need also to allow the access to this file (instead of /v3/api-docs) like this:
.requestMatchers("/swagger-ui/**", "/openapi.yml", "/swagger-ui.html" ).permitAll()


No need of parsers. You need only a basic configuration class like this:
@Configuration
public class OpenApiConfig {

    @Bean
    SpringDocConfiguration springDocConfiguration(){
        return new SpringDocConfiguration();
    }

    @Bean
    SpringDocConfigProperties springDocConfigProperties() {
        return new SpringDocConfigProperties();
    }

    @Bean
    ObjectMapperProvider objectMapperProvider(SpringDocConfigProperties springDocConfigProperties){
        return new ObjectMapperProvider(springDocConfigProperties);
    }

    @Bean
    SpringDocUIConfiguration SpringDocUIConfiguration(Optional<SwaggerUiConfigProperties> optionalSwaggerUiConfigProperties){
        return new SpringDocUIConfiguration(optionalSwaggerUiConfigProperties);
    }
}


Please note: in your Security configuration don't use httpBasic. Use formLogin instead:
    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .cors(withDefaults())
//            .httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults())  don't use it!
            .formLogin(withDefaults());

        http.authorizeHttpRequests(
          c -> c
                .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/v1/test-admin").hasRole(String.valueOf(ADMIN))
                .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/v1/test-user").hasRole(String.valueOf(USER))
                .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/v1/auth/*").permitAll()
                .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/v1/questions/").permitAll()
                .requestMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/error").permitAll() // important!
                .requestMatchers("/swagger-ui/**", "/openapi.yml", "/swagger-ui.html" ).permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
        );
        http.csrf(
                c -> c.disable()
        );
        return http.build();
    }



The other dependencies were added so that otherwise it would not pick up the configuration from openapi.yml and the swagger ui page would not appear, only v3/api-docs.

For using of own specification file please check this docu: https://springdoc.org/#what-is-a-proper-way-to-set-up-swagger-ui-to-use-provided-spec-yml

Hi, the issue happens with or without these extra dependencies.

With the code provided in the question I was not able to reproduce your problem. Your GitHub repo is not accessible for us.

Apologies as I'd forgotten to make the repo public. This is done now. Thank you.

Please check again. https://github.com/francislainy/so-be is not found 404

So sorry about that, yes, the changes were not saved. It's public now for sure.

Please check my update. The main issue with the login popup was the wrong configuration: httpBasic instead of formLogin.

Thanks so much. I've tried the changes to allow for the custom openapi.yml file and that worked. I'll try the other suggestions when I've a bit more time. However, I'm not sure how I feel about having to change how to authenticate within my application from basic to form type only to fit Swagger?

I understand. But if you have a browser UI in your project (and Swagger is one) then FormLogin is the correct one. It allows browser to manage a session instead of asking for credentials on every page. AFAIK internally it uses basic authorization with user and password. You will be able to use it for API calls without browser. Like from Postman or a microservice.

Here is what has been working for us. If you still have a problem I can take a look into the documentation to see what you are mising.
Our security configuration:
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http
            .authorizeHttpRequests((authz) -> authz
                    // need this in order to get proper errors instead of 401!!
                    .requestMatchers("/error").permitAll()
                    .requestMatchers("/api/auth/**").permitAll()
                    .requestMatchers("/api/settings/**").permitAll()
                    .requestMatchers("/swagger-ui/**").permitAll()
                    .requestMatchers("/v3/api-docs/**").permitAll()
                    .requestMatchers("/actuator/**").permitAll()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
            )
            .sessionManagement((session) -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
            .cors((cors) -> cors.configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource()))
            .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
            .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .addFilterBefore(filterChainExceptionHandler(), JwtAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .addFilterAfter(claimsFilter(), JwtAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .authenticationProvider(authProvider)
            .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
            .exceptionHandling((handler) -> handler.authenticationEntryPoint(jwtEntryPoint))
            .build();
    }

We have set up an OpenAPI bean and some application.properties denoting the packages that swagger should scan, a new URL for it etc.
@Configuration
public class SwaggerConfig {

  public static final String AUTHORIZATION_HEADER = "Authorization";

  @Value("${eligence.openapi.url}")
  private String url;

  @Bean
  public OpenAPI api() {

    Server server = new Server();
    server.setUrl(url);
    server.setDescription("Eligence Server URL");

    return new OpenAPI()
      .info(metaInfo()).servers(List.of(server))
      .components(new Components()
        .addSecuritySchemes("api_key", new SecurityScheme()
                .type(SecurityScheme.Type.APIKEY)
                .description("Api Key access")
                .in(SecurityScheme.In.HEADER)
                .name(AUTHORIZATION_HEADER)
        ))
      .security(Collections.singletonList(new SecurityRequirement().addList("api_key").addList("organization_key")));
  }

  private Info metaInfo() {
    return new Info()
            .description("Backend API Eligence Project")
            .title("Eligence API")
            .version("2.0.0");
  }

}

## Swagger
eligence.openapi.url=${OPENAPI_URL:http://localhost:9006}/eligence-service
springdoc.paths-to-match=/api/**
springdoc.show-actuator=true
springdoc.packages-to-scan=eu.eligence.core
springdoc.swagger-ui.path=/swagger-ui
springdoc.swagger-ui.operationsSorter=method

If it still does not work for you, you should add in your application properties logs to check what is going on exactly:
logging.level.root=${LOGGING_ROOT:INFO}
logging.level.org.springframework.web=${LOGGING_SPRING_WEB:INFO}

Also, you should check about the snakeyaml. Is that something you want for swagger? Because it is not needed as Mar-Z mentioned

Thank you. If you can have a look at some of the updates I've pasted here.
